# Редирект на предыдущую страницу

Tags: редирект, redirect

Ребят, нужна помощь.
В общем, на моем сайте можно залогиниться с любой страницы новости, но после авторизации выкидывает на ненужные страницы:

- Сайт/новость1/ненужная страница
- Сайт/новость2/ненужная страница
- Сайт/новость3/ненужная страница
- Сайт/новость4/ненужная страница

Как сделать так, чтобы со всех страниц с окончанием /ненужная страница шел редирект на

- Сайт/новость1/ (предыдущую страницу)?

Заранее благодарен!

Answer (score 1):

Ссылка на предыдущую страницу хранится в массиве `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`. 
Форма логина примерно будет выглядеть вот так:

```
<?php
$previous_page = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
?>
<form metod="post" action="<?php $previous_page ?> ">
   <input type="text" name="login" placeholder="введите логин" />
   <input type="password" name="password" />
   <input type="submit" name="submit" />
<form>
</pre>
```